# execution of Hadoop code without HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am having an issue running a code accessing hdfs without the command :

```
hadoop jar
```

Here is the code I try to run :

```
package com.infotel.mycompany.testhdfs;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;


/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.addResource("/opt/hadoop-2.2.0/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml");
        config.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://192.168.2.164/");

        FileSystem dfs = FileSystem.get(config);

        Path pt = new Path("/path/to/myfile");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dfs.open(pt)));
        String line;
        line = br.readLine();
        while(line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = br.readLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I build the code using maven with the following pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany.bigdata</groupId>
    <artifactId>testhdfs</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>testhdfs</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.20.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.infotel.bigdata.testhdfs.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I run my code with this command :

```
hadoop jar target/testhdfs-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.infotel.mycompany.testhdfs.App
```

It work fine. But if I run my code with this command or from Eclipse:

```
mvn exec:java
```

I get the following error :

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /path/to/myfile does not exist.
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:361)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:125)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:283)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:356)
        at com.infotel.bigdata.testhdfs.App.main(App.java:30)
```

Here is my core-site.xml :

```
<configuration>    
    <property>
         <name>fs.defaultFS</name>   
         <value>hdfs://chef</value>
         <description>NameNode URI </description>
    </property> 
    <property>       
        <name>hadoop.http.staticuser.user</name>  
        <value>hdfs</value>  
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/opt/hadoop-2.2.0/tmp</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I have the same issue when I try to run a MapReduce, I have to use the Hadoop jar command instead of running it from Eclipse. I am using Hadoop 2.2.0. It look like I totally miss something or don't understand something, Googling did not help me.

If someone have a solution I will be very thankfull. The final aim is to retrieve a file from HDFS inside a servlet, this is the reason why I cannot use `hadoop jar`

Comment: Did you notice "File /path/to/myfile does not exist"? Change it to a directory that exists

Comment: No in my real code, it's not the same URL, I change it from privacy reason. But the PATH does really exist. I double check by running `hadoop fs -cat /path/to/myfile` and when I run the following code using `hadoop jar` it does not give me the error "File does not exist" and it successfully display the file.

Comment: Does the folder have read access?  chmod it if not

Comment: Yes it does have read authorization.

Answer (score 0):

In this statement can you add the port in which your name node is started.

```
config.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://192.168.2.164/");
```

The default port for name node in Apache Hadoop  is 8020.

```
config.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://192.168.2.164:8020");
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't change anything, it still work with `hadoop jar` but it does not work without.

Comment: Was the port you have given in your core-site.xml and what you given in the above step same ?

Comment: I don't specify any port because I want to use default port whenever it's possible, I have just edited my question and I had my `core-site.xml`. I still insist on the fact that every thing work fine when I run my jar using `hadoop jar`, so I do not think it can be a problem of port or right access.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
First i did try to run my code using all the library from my Hadoop installation with this command :

```
java -cp `hadoop classpath`:target/testhdfs-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.infotel.bigdata.testhdfs.App
```

So i figure out it was a jar version problem. By searching blindly, I change my pom.xml to :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>com.mycompany.bigdata</groupId>
        <artifactId>testhdfs</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <name>testhdfs</name>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

        <properties>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>junit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                        <version>3.8.1</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.0</version>
                </dependency>

        </dependencies>

        <build>
                <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                <configuration>
                                        <mainClass>com.infotel.bigdata.testhdfs.App</mainClass>
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                </plugins>
        </build>
</project>
```

And now `mvn exec:java` work fine. Maybe hadoop-core should only be used for old Hadoop version ?
Does someone know more about hadoop-core and hadoop-common ?